# Printing the out of the scope when initialize

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, int

Why there is 5 ?

Could you please explain? I thought it will be 4

```java
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

}
System.out.println(i);//it shows 5 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i=0 is initialising the value to 0.

i++ means value of i will be incremented every time the loop runs.

And i<5 is a condition where loop check the value should be less than 5. (It will only runs if value of i will remain less than 5)

In the last increment happens when i=4  the value of i become 5 after i++.

and You are printing the value outside loop. It means value of i is already become 5.